# How to solve changelog error for building deb with sbt-native-packager?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have the following in my `build.sbt` file to use Java-based `.deb` package building and publish to an Artifactory repository:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DebianPlugin, JDebPackaging, DebianDeployPlugin)
```

However, when I try to do `debian:publish`, I get the error:

```
Creating changes file: /foo/bar/target/bar_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_all.changes
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot generate .changes file without a changelog
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.debian.DebianNativePackaging$$anonfun$debianNativeSettings$1.apply(NativePackaging.scala:49)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.debian.DebianNativePackaging$$anonfun$debianNativeSettings$1.apply(NativePackaging.scala:47)
    at scala.Function6$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function6.scala:35)
    at scala.Function6$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function6.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (debian:genChanges) Cannot generate .changes file without a changelog
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 15-Jul-2016 09:47:53
```

I tried to add

```
changelog in Debian := ""
```

to my `build.sbt` as documented in [the sbt native packager documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/debian.html#build) (well, the documentation didn't specify what type it was, but I thought sbt would tell me if I had the wrong type so that would be fine). But then I received:

```
/foo/bar/build.sbt:31: error: not found: value changelog
changelog in Debian := ""
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I searched for an example showing setting the changelog, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DebianDeployPlugin` doesn't seem to work with `JDebPackaging`, and I'm not enough of an sbt guru to figure out why.

But to just build the `.deb` file, it's enough to add:

```
debianChangelog in Debian := Some(file("debian/changelog"))
```

and create a file `debian/changelog` containing

```
project-name (x.y.z) UNRELEASED; urgency=low

     * Initial no-op application.

 -- Your Name <your.email@example.com>  Fri, 15 Jul 2016 12:18:00 +0100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also ignore changelog settings by adding following lines to build.sbt

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.SettingsHelper._
makeDeploymentSettings(Debian, packageBin in Debian, "deb")
```

This code command `dpkg-deb` to run only `deb building phase`, without `changelog generation phase`

Answer (score -1):

Try `changelog in Debian := None`.